# Is this expected behavior for String.containsOnly()?

Tags: string, bug

Here is some code to illustrate the problem.

```
String str1 = '';
System.debug(str1.containsOnly('W'));
```

I would expect `false` as the result but surprisingly the result was `true`. I don't understand why this is the case considering an empty string does not contain a `'W'` character. Is this expected behavior or a bug?

**Edit**: After the responses I have received so far, I think I need to rephrase my question and make it a more fundamental one. By so doing, the original question will answered.

One underlying assumption I am making is that the documentation of the method preceded and was the basis of the implementation of the method and not vice versa. If you think this assumption is wrong, please let me know.

Thus putting aside how `containsOnly()` is currently implemented, how should the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm)
of the method be understood? It is more of a question of meaning or semantics than a technical one. This is the given description.

> **containsOnly(inputString)**
> Returns true if the current String contains
> characters only from the specified sequence of characters and not any
> other characters; otherwise, returns false.

Here are the possible interpretations so far:

1. The current string does not contain any characters outside of the characters in the input string. (@PhilW)
2. The current string contains any of the characters in the input string (`containsAny(inputString)`) && interpretation 1. (My understanding).

Please let me know how you understand the documentation or the phrase **containsOnly** and if you have any other plausible interpretations, I will add them to the list. I think some consensus is needed on this before getting into the actual implementation of the method.

Comment: I know that when we do `'abcd'.split('')` it seperate each character so its something related to that.

Comment: Tushar - That may be true but would you say that the result was what you expected? It seems not what you would expect intuitively at least for me. This is what I feel needs to be answered so as to determine if indeed it is expected behavior or a bug.

Answer (score 8):

Logically, yes, because the empty string does not contain any disallowed characters.

Disallowed characters are any characters not explicitly listed in the "only" specification. So in this case it is any letter other than "W".

If I were implementing this method myself I would do something like:

```
public Boolean containsOnly(String allowed) {
    // "chars" is the internal array of characters in the string
    for (Integer i = 0; i < chars.size(); i++) {
        if (allowed.indexOfChar(chars[i]) < 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The point is, it is a compact iteration looking for disallowed characters with early exit as required and if you don't find any disallowed characters you simply return true.

I don't think this behaviour can be considered a bug; it is a natural outcome of checking in a compact and efficient way. You can also view an empty string as zero instances of the 'W' character. `String.containsOnly` will return true for:

- zero 'W' characters (the empty string)
- one 'W' character (the string 'W')
- two 'W' characters (the string 'WW')
- etc.

If you want to verify that you have a non-empty string and it has just the specified characters in it, adapt your code to do:

```
if (str1.isNotEmpty() && str1.containsOnly('W')) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what is meant by disallowed chars in this case? When I do `str1.contains('W')` or `''.contains('W')`, I get the expected result (i.e. returns false). Also, when I do `str1.containsOnly('abc')`, I get `true` (same result as mentioned by @user73893).

Comment: The method might be implemented as you put it but shouldn't the check be for the allowed characters? There is already a `containsNone()` method for checking disallowed characters.

Comment: +1 Thanks @PhilW for elaborating on your answer with sample snippet. Considering the possible lack of check for empty string in the apex source code for this method, this must be considered as bug (not something that most people wound run into though).

Comment: @PhilW Appreciate the additional clarification.

Comment: @PhilW Thanks for expounding on your original post but I have to point out a few points on which I have differing views.1. What you wrote was how you would implement the method but based on a premise (i.e. a string does not contain disallowed characters as the only condition that needs to be checked) that itself needs to be established.

Comment: @PhilW   2. It is true that an empty string can be viewed as zero instances of the 'W' character but you wouldn't say the empty string "contains" 'W' based on the implementation of `contains()`. Based on your zero instances premise, the result of the method will always return true for an empty string regardless of the input string 3.`if (str1.isNotEmpty() && str1.containsOnly('W'))` This is only necessary based on how the method **is** currently implemented but speaking only of how the method **should** be implemented, an empty string should also be handled within `containsOnly()`.

Comment: ContainsOnly is quite different to contains. Contains is looking for an exact sub-string. ContainsOnly is checking that the string has only the specified characters in it. The semantics are completely different. A zero length match makes entirely logical sense to me (though clearly not to you as you reject each of my explanations). Regardless, it is what it is and you have to accept this behaviour.

Comment: They are not quite different as one builds on the other in my opinion but putting that aside, using your own words, " ContainsOnly is checking that the string has only the specified characters in it", would you say a string has (this is nothing but another word for contains) certain characters in it if there are zero instances of the said characters? I would say no but you would say yes. If we concede zero instances, it ceases to be a condition as anything passes. This is the crux of the issue.

Comment: It may be true that it is what it is and I have to accept this behavior but there is nothing wrong with hoping for change even though it might never happen. Regardless, I highly appreciate your responses and input.

Answer (score 3):

I am inclined to think that **this isn't a bug and it is standard behavior, but the documentation is ambiguous at best and makes no indications as to how an empty string should operate**. Additional clarification is warranted given that `contains` and `containsOnly` return different outcomes in these scenarios:

```java
''.contains('W');     //false
''.containsOnly('W'); //true
```

**Addendum**: Some additional examples showing how this function is more *set-like* than `contains` which is looking for a substring in a given string:

```java
'abab'.containsOnly('ab');   //true
'ab'.containsOnly('abab');   //true
'abab'.containsOnly('abcd'); //true

'abab'.contains('ab');       //true
'ab'.contains('abab');       //false
'abab'.contains('abc');      //false
```

The `containsOnly` operation should be defined in mathematical terms and I have a hunch that it's implemented in that way. There isn't strictly an operation like `containsOnly` (*that I know of - I am not a mathematician*), but you can get there two ways with standard set operations. If you take the intersection (∩) of the two sets and the intersection is the same as your first operand, it's `true`, meaning the two sets overlap entirely:

> [{A,B} ∩ {A,B} = {A,B}](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7BA%2CB%7D%20%E2%88%A9%20%7BA%2CB%7D)

> [{} ∩ {A,B} = {}](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7D%20%E2%88%A9%20%7BA%2CB%7D)

But the rules of set algebra treat an [empty set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empty_set) in a unique way in that all of the following are equivalent:

> {} ∩ {A,B} ≡ {} ∩ {} ≡ {}

This would explain why an empty string, which is an empty 'set' of characters, would always return true when the operation is done on it. The intersection of the empty set with any other set (including another empty set) is always the empty set.

That was one way of implementing a `containsOnly` function using set operations. The other is to use the difference (\). If the difference of two sets is the same as your original, you could say that the first set contains only the second set. Again, the empty set behaves in a similar way as using an intersection.

> {A,B} \ {A} = {B}

> {A,B} \ {A,B} = {} ≡ [{} \ {A,B} = {}](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7D%20%5C%20%7BA%2CB%7D%20) ≡ [{} \ {} = {}](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7D%20%5C%20%7B%7D%20)

My assumption is that `containsOnly` is implemented using one of these methods for its algorithm and the documentation for the `String` class needs to be updated to reflect the current methodology of the method (so that future developers are aware of the nuances). *Or* the method should be changed to be made consist with `contains`.

Comment: Something I would add is that Salesforce documentation is always rubbish at covering edge cases and exception scenarios. One thing I would say is that the Apex team doesn't tend to introduce breaking changes in behaviour even when the documentation is lacking.